# Access multiple fields in AutoSuggestBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is it possible to access the equivalent of SelectedValuePath of a ComboBox in the AutoSuggestBox in UWP?  Basically I'm trying to display one value as the Display Text and a "hidden" value with the ID of the Display Text that I can access in the code behind when the Suggestion is chosen.

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="TxtRegNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  TextChanged="TxtRegNumber_OnTextChanged"  
                        SuggestionChosen="TxtRegNumber_OnSuggestionChosen" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="296" UpdateTextOnSelect="True" TextMemberPath="VehicleRegNumber" 
                        DisplayMemberPath="VehicleRegNumber" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="#FFFDFCFC" PlaceholderText="Enter vehicle reg number" Margin="379,360,349,249">
       </AutoSuggestBox>
```

Comment: If your questions is `Is it possible` then **Yes**, If you want to know **how**, post your code on how you are filling the `AutoSuggestBox` so that we can help you.

Comment: sorry about that and thanks :)